# cross compiling Why configure script -- not able to find X11/Xlib.h?

Tags: wxwidgets, x11, cross-compiling

cross compiling wxGTK on Ubantu --- Why configure script -- not able to find X11/Xlib.h ?

I am using cross compiler -- arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi :------
http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/05/26/how-to-build-a-cross-compiler-for-your-raspberry-pi/

I am getting error while running configure for wxGTK.
http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started

> I have already installed -- gtk+ for linux.

I have installed :----

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install wx2.8-headers libwxgtk2.8-0 libwxgtk2.8-dev

Its here :------

> /usr/include/gtk-2.0/

Xlib.h is here :------------

> test -f /usr/include/X11/Xlib.h && echo "exists"
>   Returns -- exists

when i run configure command :-------

> `../configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --build= i686-pc-linux --enable-unicode --prefix=/opt/wxGTK_RPI_build`

configure.log file --- Xlib.h not detected :---------

```
>configure:32521: checking for X11/Xlib.h
>configure:32537: arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c   conftest.c >&5
>conftest.c:71:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Xlib.h is not found :----

So when i use to give - make :--------
I get error because of this

```
>../src/unix/utilsx11.cpp:31:22: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
>make: *** [coredll_utilsx11.o] Error 1
```

If Xlib.h is there then why it is not found ?????????

```
>Even i have added to PATH -->>   /usr/include/X11/
```

More details about problem faced :--
http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=36772&start=15

Please suggest.

Comment: A cross compiler does not normally search `/usr/include`. Try `your-gcc -v` to see the the default path. Using a natively installed package such as X11 for cross builds is not going to work anyway, because the libraries are not there.

Comment: @nm -----  Just One last suggestion i need :----

When i run :----
../configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi 

. And configure log o/p contains :----
 not able to find X11/Xlib.h 


This mean configure script is -- looking in my cross compiler standard specific path -- >arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi
And it does not find X11 there & throws this error ?

Is it right.

Comment: I'm don't know how configure looks for include files. Your guess seems to be correct but it's best to look inside the script to be sure

Answer (score 0):

It certainly means that the compiler needs the X11 headers for ARM.

So you have to cross-compile X11 for ARM first.